# Removing outlier from a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I am removing outliers from a dataset.

I decided to remove outlier from each column one-by-one. I have columns with a different number of missing values.

I used this code but it removed the whole row containg the outlier and due to many NaN values in my data, number of rows of my data reduced drastically.

```py
def remove_outlier(df_in, col_name):
    q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1 #Interquartile range
    fence_low  = q1-1.5*iqr
    fence_high = q3+1.5*iqr
    df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
    return df_out
```

Then I decided to remove outlier from each column, and fill ouliers with NaN in each column
I wrote this code

```py
def remove_outlier(df_in, col_name, thres=1.5):
    q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1 #Interquartile range
    fence_low  = q1-thres*iqr
    fence_high = q3+thres*iqr
    mask = (df_in[col_name] > fence_high) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_low)
    df_in.loc[mask, col_name] = np.nan
    return df_in
```

But this code doesn't filters the outliers. gave the same result.

What is wrong in this code? How can I correct it?

Is there any other elegant method to filter outlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the condition once. How can that be `&`. It should be `|`

Comment: Should I filter outlier for all columns at once, or should I do it one-by-one (changing the thresholds according to specific columns)?

Answer (score 1):

```
df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
```

In this snipplet, you select rows based on `df_in[col_name] > fence_low` and `df_in[col_name] < fence_high`, hence each time one of these condition is not respected, the row will be removed;

As a general rule, if you have a column with 30% outliers, 30% of you dataset will disappear, and you have two options
1. Fill the missing value `ffill, mean constant value ...`
2. Or drop these feature, if it is not mandatory, because in some times you would better drop a feature than reduce your dataset too much

Hope it helps